# Modifying FullScreen Design for ListPicker 

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone-7

I've Been working with WP7 for a while, am using listPicker/DatePicker Heavily. i hate its design though.i use liskPicker's property ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly". i tried to make those controls to look prettier by

// Setting A source to the FullModeItemTemplate
`FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource lpkFullItemTemplate}"`

//the definition for this Resource is as follows:

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFullItemTemplate">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5 5 5 5" Background="#FFA3A3A3" 
  Width="475" Height="45" >
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  Foreground="Black" Margin="5 5 15 5"  />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I need real changes, changing the background of that popup and such changes, is that possible? or i need to build my own popup from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that you will have to create a copy of the [ListPickerPage.xaml](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/74775#1510235) file from the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit in your application, change it to meet your requirements, and then on your ListPicker control set the PickerPageUri proprety to the new ListPickerPage.xaml

Comment: Sorry, but... how to actually do this? I mean, i copied the  ListPickerPage.xaml into my project, but it needs the correspoding .xaml.cs (OnPickerTapped event handler). So i add it too, but then a lot of warnings and errors appear because of missing or inaccessible references.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as Felipe.  I see "just copy it" written everywhere but I can't figure out how.  I copied the xaml and even copied in the xaml.cs file, but I couldn't make that work without really disassembling and recreating the functionality because the code references a lot of references to internal fields.  I guess maybe ListPicker passes some sort of reference to itself so you just gotta fake enough of ListPickerPage to manipulate the ListPicker when the user selects an item?  But I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to improve Pedro's answer, but I still can't comment. You can see there's some people making questions up there.

In order to copy the `ListPickerPage` you'll need both the `ListPickerPage.xaml` and `ListPickerPage.xaml.cs` files. If you want those files to compile, you need some extension methods defined on [Extensions.cs](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/Common/Extensions.cs), [ItemsControlExtensions.cs](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit/Common/ItemsControlExtensions.cs) and `VisualTreeExtensions.cs`. You can either copy those three files or cherry pick the methods you need and add them to your own file.

Comment: I understand that what you said is needed but like I said on other posts this wasn't enough. I still couldn't make this to work. Yes the new modified full screen page opens normally with no exceptions BUT everything there is set to null.. no items, no header..nothing.

Comment: Ah, yes, there's a problem as explained in [this issue](https://phone.codeplex.com/workitem/11515). In the end I had to copy the ListPicker control code into my project.